# Best method to cache data android app

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, caching

Which is the best method to cache data coming from a restful webservice locally in Android app (categories, products, ..)? XML, sqlite or something else? Which is the best approach from performance point of view? and what about the size of the app?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options to consider.

As a whole, I would say the best method is to rely on what others have figured out, and not re-inventing the wheel.

For a restful webservice take a look at [Square's Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which relies [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) which relies on HTTP caching standards, which uses [DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache/) for caching to memory and later to disk.

Using this technique will allow the caching layer to be automated and you dont have to worry about it, while gaining the benefits.

This is kind of the umbrella use case though. It really depends on what you need, but for the most part this technique should cover your bases.